# Definition of convergence with strict and weak inequalities.

Tags: real-analysis

Firstly, I apologise if this is a somewhat trivial question but it's been niggling me for a while. As a non-maths specialist I'm concerned I've made a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere. In very non precise language, it concerns the difference between statements of the form $d(x,y)\leq \epsilon$ and $d(x,y)<\epsilon$. I'm happy with the following basic fact.

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Then if $|x|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0 \iff x=0$ and similarly, if $|x|\leq\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0 \iff x=0$

The example that I find a bit strange comes from an economics textbook "Recursive Methods in Economic Dynamics" and concerns the proof that $CB(X)$ the set of continuous and bounded functions on $X\subset \mathbb{R}^l$ is complete in the sup norm. The authors state that our goal, as we know, is to prove that every Cauchy sequence in $CB(X)$ converges to some limit in $CB(X)$.

In other words we need to show $||f-f_n||\leq \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. But why would we phrase it like this rather than saying $||f-f_n||< \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. This seems more natural, given the way we define convergence of a Cauchy sequence (and in general). Given the proof, I'm happy that it can easily be altered to the latter.

Comment: Most of the time, with such $\epsilon$ proofs, we can modify a weak inequality to a strict inequality or vice-versa, precisely because the quantifier is "for all $\epsilon>0$". Similarly, if in the process of a proof one arrives at $... \leq 29\epsilon$. This is also perfectly fine. It is usually only in a very introductory rigorous analysis course where we pay close attention to such small details (as we should), but after a while, the various equivalences become clear even without explicit mention, hence we do not really bother trying to finish a proof perfectly with $... <\epsilon$.

Comment: That seems fair enough. I'm certainly happy that they're the same. Just wanted to know why you would choose one over the other.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no difference whether you have $\|f-f_n\| \leq \epsilon$ or $\|f-f_n\| < \epsilon$ in the definition. Suppose you have $\|f-f_n\| \leq \epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$. [Here again it makes no difference whether you say $n >n_0$ or $n \geq n_0$].  Then given $\epsilon >0$ choose $n_0$ such that  $\|f-f_n\| \leq \epsilon/2$ for all $n \geq n_0$. Then we have $\|f-f_n\| <\epsilon$ for all $n \geq n_0$.

Comment: I'm happy with that. Im just unsure why you would pick one over the other when they're pretty much the same. Why would the authors decide to formulate like this? The only reason I can think of is that in the proof we take limits of a weak inequality which doesn't change the inequality. If we set it up as a strict inequality that would obviously cause it to turn into a weak inequality.

Comment: @mark I think it is as you said. When limits and $\sup$s and triangle inequalities are involved, non-strict inequalities can be more convenient.